# Feedback regarding review suspension

Tags: discussion, reviewing

I have been suspended from reviewing, and I believe it is unjustified.

[image]
See the review in question [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/188986/in-super-mario-bros-which-button-is-used-to-run-and-to-jump/383197#383197). I reviewed it as 'Not an answer'.

[image]
The question can be found [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/383168/how-can-i-get-better-at-building-in-fallout-4/383170#383170). I reviewed it as 'Looks OK'.

This is the feedback I got:

> You approved answers that should have been deleted instead. If you believe an answer is "in no way constructive", then please review it with *Recommend Deletion*. If a post does not attempt to answer a question, then please flag it as Not an Answer.

I believe both of my flags are completely reasonable:

- The first reviewed answer ("A is not working for some reason") **is not** an answer to the question "In Super Mario Bros which button is used to run and to jump?".
- The second reviewed answer ("Just keeps practicing") **is** an answer to the question "How can I get better at building in Fallout 4?". It's not a *good* answer, that's why I left a comment, but it *is* an answer.

Furthermore, the feedback given seemingly only addresses the second of these reviews I performed. And the first reviewed answer got deleted anyway.

There have been several more unapproved flags throughout my activity record which I think were refuted for the wrong reasons, but since reviewing takes a certain amount of interpretation (both for moderators and us plebs) I never wanted to bring them up and make a big deal out of any of those. Yet now I feel this is an unwarranted disapproval of the time I spent here trying to be a constructive part of the community. Don't get me wrong, I know I make mistakes, but in this case I can't discern them.

I look forward to a more in-depth reaction from the moderator who blocked me from the review queues.

Comment: Not a mod but all looks fine to me.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf In what way? :)

Comment: Sorry, bad wording! Your reviews look accurate.

Comment: I'm not the mod who issued the review suspension,  but one thing to keep in mind is that a short review suspension isn't really intended to be a punishment. It's more about just putting a temporary hold on your reviews until we know you've had a chance to review moderator feedback on them.

Comment: @Wipqozn Sure, that sounds reasonable, but in that case you may interpret my question as: what can I learn from this feedback? Because I don't know.

Comment: Is this just going to be ignored until the suspension is over? I'd still like a response.

Comment: You could [contact](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/contact) them regarding the situation, but it will take a while for you to receive a response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the first review

> See the review in question [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/383170/143571). I reviewed it as 'Not an answer'.

The actual review can be found [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/302723). As you can see, you reviewed the post with "No Action Needed". Hence the part of the feedback message saying

> If a post does not attempt to answer a question, then please flag it as *Not an Answer*.

For the second review

> The question can be found [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/383170/143571). I reviewed it as 'Looks OK'.

The actual review can be found [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/302683). You reviewed the post as "Looks OK", but you left a comment saying the answer is "in no way constructive". If you feel the need to post that comment, it's very strange to review the post as "Looks OK", meaning it doesn't need any other edits to be a good answer. Hence the part of the feedback message saying

> If you believe an answer is "in no way constructive", then please review it with *Recommend Deletion*.

You said

> It's not a *good* answer, that's why I left a comment, but it *is* an answer.

However the queue is called [Low Quality Queue](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/review-low-quality). The point is to delete posts that are of such low quality as to be completely unhelpful. This includes posts that are not answers, but is not limited to them. Indeed, the help page linked mentions

> - **Recommend deletion** or **Delete** if you think that an answer does not address the question at all, is link-only, or is incomprehensible. Do not vote to delete answers that are simply wrong. You may leave a comment explaining the issues with the answer, or choose one of the provided canned comments.

Commenting that an answer is "in no way constructive" seems to fall squarely into this case.

A review suspension is not meant to be a punishment, especially the first time. It is meant to be a way to let you know "Hey, we've noticed something weird in your reviews, maybe it could help to slow down a little and make sure you're choosing the right action". Given this meta post, the suspension seems to have helped in that regard.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Wrigglenite. I remember reading that flagging an answer as 'Not an answer' should not be used when a post is simply low-quality (I think it was actually we who discussed it). I must say that disagreeing with my vote only because my comment *seems* to contradict that vote is a little weird to me (not unlike judging a question by its answers). Note that I used 'not constructive' in the sense that the answer does not try to actively improve the situation of the OP, yet the answer was in no way incorrect.

Comment: "Not an answer" is for posts that are not answers, but the Low Quality Queue is not just for posts that are not answers.

Comment: As for the other review: since there is a comment by me stating that it does not provide an answer, I must have flagged it as such. I think what happened was that I had two different queues open in two different tabs, and I couldn't use that same flag again. I will try to prevent that in the future, that was a mistake. Yet, I still see no reason for the suspension, if these examples are the best arguments for that action, and if "acting weird" is sufficient grounds.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean by your comment.

Comment: The "Not an answer" flag is not the only way that posts get to the Low Quality Queue, as detailed in the help page I linked in the post.